# How to copy structures that involve pointers in C?

Tags: c

I have a vector type defined as follows:

```
typedef struct vector {
    void **items;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int size;
} vector_st;

typedef vector_st *vector_t;
```

And I allocate and free it as follows:

```
vector_t vector_init(unsigned int capacity)
{
    vector_t v = (vector_t)calloc(1, sizeof(vector_st));
    v->capacity = capacity;
    v->size = 0;
    v->items = malloc(sizeof(void *) * v->capacity);
    return v;
}

void vector_free(vector_t v)
{
    if (v) {
        free(v->items);
        v->capacity = 0;
        v->size = 0;
        free(v);
        v = NULL;
    }
}
```

Now, the point is that I want to copy one vector to another one, meaning including all its content. So, I tried to define a function like this:

```
void vector_copy(vector_t to, vector_t from)
{
    memcpy(to, from, sizeof(vector_st));
}
```

But, this does not seem to work quite right, as when I do something like this:

```
vector_t vec = vector_init(3);
vector_add(vec, 1);
vector_add(vec, 2);
vector_add(vec, 3);

unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < vec->size; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", (int)vector_get(vec, i));
}

vector_t copied = vector_init(3);
vector_copy(copied, vec);
vector_free(vec);

for (i = 0; i < copied->size; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", (int)vector_get(copied, i));
}
```

For the first vector it correctly prints `1 2 3` but for the second one it prints `0 2 3`. So, basically I believe it just copies maybe the memory addresses and not the actual content, as when I free the first vector the first element is set to 0. Any ideas how to copy this structure in my case?

**EDIT:**

```
void vector_resize(vector_t v, unsigned int capacity)
{
    void **items = realloc(v->items, sizeof(void *) * capacity);
    if (items) {
        v->items = items;
        v->capacity = capacity;
    }
}

void vector_add(vector_t v, void *item)
{
    if (v->capacity == v->size) {
        vector_resize(v, v->capacity * 2);
    }
    v->items[v->size++] = item;
}
```

Comment: *`memcpy(to, from, sizeof(vector_st));`* What's wrong with `*to = *from;`?

Comment: You have the same problem with the `memcpy()`.

Comment: @melpomene Because it will produce the same result I have as with `memcpy()`, and that is not the intended result. As Richard pointed out above.

Comment: Can you paste the code to `vector_add`? Also, what do you mean by "copies the memory addresses and not the actual content"? From the code you've shown us, the only content in the vector is a collection of memory addresses.

Comment: Because you are using pointers you have a shallow copy versus deep copy decision to make. When you do the copy do you just copy the pointers over or do you make a copy of the data pointed to? Currently you do a shallow copy which results in memory leak on the copy as well as when you `free()` the object being copied, you also `free()` the copied to pointers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Just pasted.

Comment: @terett Your `vector_add` takes `void *` and you call it to add values like `1` and `2`. Are you just using `void*` as a generic value class or are you expecting it to point to something?

Comment: I use it as generic value class, so I can add elements of different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, the point is that I want to copy one vector to another one, meaning including all its content.

What you seem to want to perform is called a "deep copy".  That means copying not just the data, but any additional pointed-to data, recursively.  You have judged correctly that `memcpy()` of the structure itself does not do this; the vector elements are pointed to by pointers in the structure, but they themselves are elsewhere, and therefore are not copied.

What's worse, you have a fundamental problem here with copying the pointed-to data: your copy function doesn't know how big the pointed-to elements are.  Without such knowledge, it is impossible to copy them.  Furthermore, if the elements themselves contain pointers, then to perform a true deep copy, you need information about which members those are, and how large are the objects to which *they* point.  *Etc*.

Basically, then, it is impossible write a generic deep copy (in any language).  Performing a deep copy requires information at every level about what you are copying.  To give you a bit of a flavor, however, you could copy one level deeper if you could rely on the vector elements being of a consistent size that is known at call time.  That might look something like this:

```
void vector_copy(vector_t to, vector_t from, size_t element_size) {
    // NOTE: robust code would check for memory allocation failures.  This code does not.
    void **temp_items;

    to->capacity = from->capacity;
    to->size = from->size;

    // evaluates to NULL if allocation fails:
    temp_items = realloc(to->items, from->capacity * sizeof(*to->items));
    to->items = temp_items;

    for (int i = 0; i < from->size; i++) {
        to->items[i] = malloc(element_size);  // evaluates to NULL if allocation fails
        memcpy(to->items[i], from->items[i], element_size);
    }
}
```

You could avoid the need to pass the element size by instead making it a member of the vector structure.

Note that this assumes that vector `to` has been initialized, and that it is not necessary to free the pointers to the individual items, if any, that are currently in it (i.e. the vector does not own these, and is therefore not responsible for managing their memory).

Comment: The leaks the contents `to->items` from before the copy.

Comment: Yes, I assume the space is already allocated, so it is only intended to be a state change operation.

Comment: Ok, @DavidSchwartz, the primary memory leak is fixed, and I've added some commentary about managing the memory for the vector elements.

Answer (score 1):

> So, basically I believe it just copies maybe the memory addresses and not the actual content

Yes, because at this line

```
memcpy(to, from, sizeof(vector_st));
```

you simply discards whatever memory was allocated for `to`, so memory held by `copied` becomes leaked; and after `vector_free(vec)` `copied` now holds a dangling reference to an already-freed memory.

To copy vector's contents into another, well, copy it:

```
memcpy(to->items, from->items, sizeof(void *) * from->size);
```

(Or less efficient

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < from->size; ++i) to->items[i] = from->items[i];
```

)

Or, better, define a copy-constructor:

```
vector_t vector_copy(vector_t src);
    // this functions allocates a fresh vector on heap;
    // set its size and capacity to those of src;
    // sets its items to a fresh array on heap of capacity elements;
    // copies src's items into that array;
    // and returns it
```

Comment: The OP appears to have fooled you: `vector_t` is already a pointer type, and there does not appear to be any need for an additional level of indirection.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I had thought the same thing until I saw this comment. `typedef`s for pointers are really misleading when glancing at function signatures.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, edited. Long posts are hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
void vector_copy(vector_t to, vector_t from)
{
    memcpy(to, from, sizeof(vector_st));
}
```

This is wrong because the `vector` owns its `items` object. So you need to do four things in `vector_copy`:

1) Free the existing `items` objects in the destination vector so that it's not leaked.
2) Copy the `capacity` and `size`.
3) Allocate a brand new `items` for the destination vector to own.
4) Copy the source `items` into the newly-allocated destination `items`.

If you consider `vector_copy` to be an initialization function, skip step 1. But in that case, I'd strongly suggest changing the name to `vector_init` so that it's clear that it creates a new vector.

Comment: No, it's not supposed to be an initialization function. Just state change.

Comment: @terett In that case, you can consolidate steps 1 and 3 into a resize operation.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply trying to access free()d memory. First you're calling `free(v->items)` in `vector_free()`, and then you're trying to print its contents as if nothing had happened!

When you copy a vector to another (no matter how) the new vector will hold a reference to `old_vector->items`, so you cannot just free() it -- C is not a garbage collected language and `malloc` doesn't reference-count the blocks it's managing.